# Iterating the click on elements through wedriver.io and nodejs implementation of selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, cucumber, bdd, webdriver-io

When I log in to my application, I am being shown a number of broadcast messages which may or may not be shown and whose number is not under my control. I need to click on a checkbox and next button to dismiss one message and move to the next. So, I need to write a loop on basis of a common element present on the messages with webdriver.io and node.js
I am new to selenium with node.js and webdriver.io and trying to write webdriver.io fucntion inside while and if loop, correct me if that is not possible

The code which I have used is below :

```
                            //Code to loop the click on elements depending upon presence of an Element
                            //Gherkin- I should see if Elementxyz exist then I click on Elementabc and Elementdef
                            //Author : Rohit
                            this.Then(/^I should see if "([^"]*)" exist then I click on "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$/, function (selectorelement, selectorcheckbox, selectornext) {
                                            // Element whose presence is checked
                                            selectorelement = this.getSelector(selectorelement);
                                            //Checkbox which needs to be ticked
                                            selectorcheckbox = this.getSelector(selectorcheckbox);
                                            //next button which needs to be clicked
                                            selectornext = this.getSelector(selectornext);

                                            return this.client
                                                            .waitForElemReady(selectornext, this.TIMEOUT_CONST)
                                                            .then(function(){

                                            if(this.client.isExisting(selectorelement))

                                            {
                                                            while(this.client.isExisting(selectorelement))
                                                            {

                                                                            this.client
                                                                                            .click(selectorcheckbox)
                                                                                            .click(selectornext)
                                                                                            .pause(12000)
                                                            }
                                            }

                            else{
                                            console.log("you got lucky there are no messages this time :)")
                            }
                                            }.bind(this));    });
```

Please help me as i am new to node.js and wedriver.io world

Hi t33n ,

i have tried the below code and loop is working fine now only thing is that my script is not waiting as .pause() is not working. Could you please help in that.

When I log in to my application, I am being shown a number of broadcast messages which may or may not be shown and whose number is not under my control. I need to click on a checkbox and next button to dismiss one message and move to the next. So, I need to write a loop on basis of a element present on the messages with webdriver.io and node.js I am new to selenium with node.js and webdriver.io and trying to write webdriver.io function for loop.

The code which i am trying to use is working and looping, only thing is giving me problem is pause which is not working as i need to pause a bit till the next message appears.

this.Then(/^I should see if "([^"]*)" exist then I click on "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$/, function (selectorelement, selectorcheckbox, selectornext) {

```
                                            selectorelement = this.getSelector(selectorelement);



                                            // Checking presence of selectorcheckbox

                                            selectorcheckbox = this.getSelector(selectorcheckbox);

                                            selectornext = this.getSelector(selectornext);



                                            var flag1 = false;
```

// function used for loop

```
                                            function runNext(flag1,selectorcheckbox, selectornext,browser) {



                                                            setTimeout(function (){

                                                                            browser

                                                                                   .isExisting(selectorcheckbox)

                                                                                    .then(function (isExisting) {

                                                                                         flag1 = isExisting;



                                                                                                 if (flag1) {



                                                                                                      flag1 = false;

                                                                                                                    browser.click(selectorcheckbox)

                                                                                                                                            .pause(1000)

                                                                                                                                            .click(selectornext)

                                                                                                                                            .pause(5000); // Pause statements not working
```

runNext(flag1, selectorcheckbox, selectornext, browser);

```
                                                                                                            }



                                            else {



                                                   console.log("no messages left or no messages this time");

                                                                                                            }



                                                                                            }, 50000)

                                                            }

                                                                            .bind(this));

                                            }



                                            var loop= runNext(flag1,selectorcheckbox, selectornext,this.client);

                            });
```

.pause statements are only working when i am doing return this.client.pause but this stops the execution wherever i write this line.

Please help me with some solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this working for you. If not you should see how loops can work and you can create your own loop with this.

```
function loop() {

client
.isVisible(selectornext).then(function(isVisible) {
if (isVisible) {

  client
  .isVisible(selectorelement).then(function(isVisible2) {
  if (isVisible2) {

        client
        .click(selectorcheckbox)
        .pause(1000)
        .click(selectornext)
        .pause(12000)
        loop()

  } // if (isVisible2) {
  }) // .isVisible(selectorelement).then(function(isVisible2) {


} // if (isVisible) {
else{
// cancel loop here?    
}
}) // .isVisible(selectornext).then(function(isVisible) {

} // function loop() {
```

Comment: I tried using like this but my browser.pause() statement is not working.